# How to crop image with dimensions (without quality loss) in PHP?

Tags: php, crop

I need to crop the image with PHP by using the dimensions.

And save it into the local with JPEG format.

Dimensions that i receive is,

```
  {"left":82.5,"top":48.875,"width":660,"height":371.25}
```

I need to crop from Original size of the image.

Ex. image is 1200x800, then the result image dimension from the actual size, not resizing or any. Because the quality should be same.

How could i use these params to crop the image ?

Is it possible ?

Comment: what dimensions are those values? 0.5 px will be hard to generate

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in **[imagick class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php)**:

```
$image = realpath("/path/to/your/image.extension");
$cropped = realpath("/path/to/your/output/image.png");

$imObj = new Imagick();
$imObj->cropImage($width, $height, $offset_x, $offset_y);
$imObj->setImageFormat("png"); // this is unnesesary, you can force an image format with the extension of the output filename.
$imObj->writeImage($cropped);
```

As for lossless output, use an image format with lossless encoding. PNG is perfect for the job, since it was designed for network transfer (hence the "Adam-7" interlacing). 
Check this related question about lossless image formats on graphic design stack:

[**What are lossless image formats?**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/128/what-are-lossless-image-formats)

Comment: Imagick is ***not*** built in `This » PECL extension is not bundled with PHP. `

Answer (score 0):

You can use [imageCopyResampled](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) function which was designed pretty much exactly for this.

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFileURL);
/***
 * resize values (imported)
 ***/
$left = 82;
$top = 49;
$width = 660;
$height = 371;

/***
 * Create destination image
 ***/
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width,$height);
$saveToFile = "destintion filespace of image file.jpg"

if(imagecopyresampled($newImage, $image, //dest/source images
        0, 0,                            // dest coordinates
    $left, $top,                         // source coordinates
   $width, $height,                      // size of area to paste to
   $width, $height                       // size of area to copy from
  )){
    imagejpeg($newImage,$saveToFile,100); //zero compression saved to file
    print "image resized ok!!";
}
```

The new fileimage will be the size specified with `$width`,`$height` and will be offset from the original image by the values given in `$left` and `$top`. From your question this looks like what you want. This will not resize or change the compression of the image (until you save the file and then possibly set these details yourself).